How can I avoid to using too many "if" in Kotlin?
I want to create a word guess game and these words will have answers. How can I control random word's meaning instead of this?
val list = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
val key = listOf("onek", "twok", "threek", "fourk", "fivek")

if(binding.randomWord.text == list[0]) {

    binding.wordMeaning.text = key[0]
}

if(binding.randomWord.text == list[1]) {

    binding.wordMeaning.text = key[1]
}

if(binding.randomWord.text == list[2]) {

    binding.wordMeaning.text = key[2]
}

if(binding.randomWord.text == list[3]) {

    binding.wordMeaning.text = key[3]
}

if(binding.randomWord.text == list[4]) {

    binding.wordMeaning.text = key[4]
}

I want to learn the other way of this method.

Use a loop in this simple case

It would be best to create a Map and to set key to value pairs for the word and the answers to them. Finally, you can reduce using if statements by using a when statement instead of if. The when statement will take in the user's choice and through the map be able to return the respective answer to them.
Example:
val map = mapOf("one" to "onek", "two" to "twok")

when (binding.randomWord.text) {
    "one", "two" -> map[binding.randomWord.text]
}


If this is the only/main way how you use this data, then I think it shouldn't be stored as two separate lists in the first place. Data structure that maps from one item to another is, well, map:
val map = mapOf(
    "one" to "onek",
    "two" to "twok",
//        ...
)

println(map["one"]) // onek

This is much easier to handle in the code, but is also much faster than searching through a list. And we can still access both original collections with map.keys and map.values. Technically, they are no longer lists, but items are still correctly ordered.
If your data is initially stored as two lists and you can't change this, I still suggest to create a map, and store it somewhere to not build it every time. This is as simple as:
val map = list.zip(key).toMap()

This approach is also not very specific to Kotlin. Maps/dictionaries exist in most programming languages and we should/could use them in similar cases.

since the answer(key) for each question(list) will be in the same index, you can find the index of the question using list.indexOf().
binding.wordMeaning.text = key[list.indexOf(binding.randomWord.text)]


The one-line version of @broot is even shorter.

You can use a for loop.  In Kotlin, it'd be something like:
for (idx in list.indices) {
    
    if(binding.randomWord.text == list[idx]) {
        binding.wordMeaning.text = key[idx]
    }
}

Just make sure your arrays are always the same length or you'll get erroneous results.

use the inner Syntactic sugar to make you code much simple and cleaner.
Step1 define dictionary of words and meaning by an immutable map
val words = mapOf(
    "one" to "one1",
    "two" to "one2"
)

Step2 select a random and update UI
words.keys.random().also { randonWord ->
    binding.randomWord.text = randonWord
}


The .also function is a scoping function in kotlin that operates on object and returns the object itself.
Inside the .also, the randomWord is set on binding.randomWord.


I got you,
Always try to use when statements when there is multiple conditions.
val list = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
val key = listOf("onek", "twok", "threek", "fourk", "fivek")

val index = list.indexOf(binding.randomWord.text)

// Use when expression to set the word meaning based on the index
binding.wordMeaning.text = when (index) {
   0 -> key.getOrElse(0) { "" } 
   1 -> key.getOrElse(1) { "" } 
   2 -> key.getOrElse(2) { "" }  
   3 -> key.getOrElse(3) { "" } 
   4 -> key.getOrElse(4) { "" } 
   else -> ""                    
}


I think you can also do it like this:
val list = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
val key = listOf("onek", "twok", "threek", "fourk", "fivek")

val index = list.indexOf(binding.randomWord.text)

if (index < key.size) {
    binding.wordMeaning.text = key[index]
}

This answer only improvement of @Mohammed Shahbaz answer
